# Download canvas as image, but add additional text from DOM textarea in image

Tags: javascript, canvas, download

I have canvas element (I use Fabric.JS). On the screen below canvas there is Dom `textarea`.

I have download button, it works - it downloads `canvas` element as image.
However, I need to add text in `textarea` text also into this download image. It should be below `canvas`.

How this should be done? I do not have an idea how to implement this trick?

Code (it is typescript and used in React app, but it doesn't matter here I guess, because if it would be pure Javascript idea would be the same - create dummy a element and trigger click)

```
const url = canvas.toDataURL({
      format: "png",
      width,
      height,
    });
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "download";
    const clickHandler = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        a.remove();
      }, 150);
    };
    a.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    a.click();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can increase the canvas height to let a space below the draw but inside the canvas.
Then you draw the text inside the canvas directly before export it as an image.

Here is an example that you can adapt :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        text = document.getElementById('text'),
        link = document.getElementById('link'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = "200";
canvas.height = "225"; // Make the height bigger that the main draw

// Draw something
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler () {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 225, 200, 20); // Clear just the text part
    ctx.font = "20px serif";
    ctx.fillText(text.value, 0, 220);

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = 'filename.png';
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    delete a;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="link">Download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if it is what you are asking ;)

Edit : It is a snippet here, it won't let you download the image. You can run it in local to see it work.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "I need to add text also into this download image"?

One download has its own mime type: it can be either text or image, but not both simultaneously.

If you mean you want an image higher than the canvas where the higher part is the canvas image and the lower part is the text, you can:

1. create another canvas with the right dimension
2. copy the content of the source canvas in the second canvas
3. use fillText or strokeText to render the text in the lower part of the second canvas
4. download the second canvas image rather than the source one

Another option could be to create a zip file containing two files: an image (dumped from the canvas) and a txt file containing the text and download it...

If you mean something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Best solution would be having one image that will contain "canvas drawing" + "text from texterea if need converted to image"

Comment: So @renathy I should already gave you the answer. On [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas) you should be able to find how to work with canvas dimension and how to grab and paste the content from a canvas to another.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to get the actual text from a canvas.

As I see it you have two choices.

One is save the text to the textarea before filling the canvas with it ( this ofcourse if you are the one that is creating the canvas and you are not just found it already in that form)

Second is send the image created from the canvas to your server and try getting the text with an exif tool. there are some javascript OCR (Optical Character Recognition ) tools out there but haven't tested any of them yet.